# How do I attach VS2013u4 debugger to my app (on a device) before I launch the app?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, visual-studio-cordova

My problem is my windows phone 8.1 app runs fine after initial install, but when the user force quits the app or the OS destroys the app it will not launch again. All I get is the splash screen and then it returns to the phone's home screen, the app must be deleted and reinstalled to be able to launch it again.

Oddly, the app will relaunch after a force quit when run on the emulator. The fail-on-launch happens only when running on a windows phone 8.1 device.

I need to be able to attach the debugger after I force quit my app so I can see what's broken when the app is launched by the user.

Comment: If you launch app in phone, force quit and then launch with debugger attached (press F5), what happens? Does your app throws any exception?

Comment: @Tawpie There's a limit on how many developer apps that can be installed on the system.  I forgot how many, but uninstall all apps that you have develop to clear up the space, then do a clean build and see if that helps you out.

Comment: @Tawpie, have you tried the suggestion provided by Abhishek? Let us know what you find out when the app is launch with the debugger attached.

Comment: I have not had the time as yet! I always though F5 was the same as clicking the "Device (run)" button -- clicking Device (run) works fine because it reloads the app. I'll try F5 shortly. Thanks.

Comment: F5 does indeed rebuild and reload the app so that's not a working alternative... drat.